# SQL update statement is executing but updating with incorrect values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update one of my tables with values from different table. The update statement executes but it doesn't update the column with the correct values.

For example,

This is `table1` where I want to update column `SID` from `table2`
[image]

This is `table2` where column `SID` contains values I need.

[image]

What I'm trying accomplish is to update `table1` from `table2` where `uID`, `NO` are equal and `table1.NO` is not null

Here's how I do it:

```
update c1 set c1.SID = c2.SID
from table1 c1, table2 c2
    where c1.UID = '09999138181408374834'
    and c1.NO = c2.NO
    and c1.NO is not null
```

It updates 5 rows, but this is the output:

[image]

Those updated SIDs in `table1` are not the same as SIDs in `table2`

Any suggestion on why it's happening and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the debugging process by verifying that this query returns the correct tuples for the update:

```
select
     c1.NO as NO_target
    ,c2.NO as NO_source
    ,c1.SID as SID_old
    ,c2.SID as SID_new
from table1 c1
join table2 c2
   on c1.NO = c2.NO
  and c1.UID = c2.UID   -- I believe this line is needed to prevent a partial Cartesian product
where c1.UID = '09999138181408374834'
  and c1.NO is not null
```

Once the query above is returning the correct tuples for the update, the process of correcting the update is simple.

Comment: That's the the problem I'm having. When I do an update it only updates 5 rows, but when I do a select it returns `49670` rows.

Comment: @user1426542: Did you run the query **exactly** as I typed it above?

Comment: @user1426542: how about with the additional JOIN clause I added above.

Comment: Yes, now it's returning only 5 rows when I added `c1.UID=c2.UID`

Comment: @Pieter: Great piece of information. I am going to use this method to debug my SQL queries Thanks buddy.

Comment: Sorry, I did test the `select` statement but I never had a chance to test the `update` statement. Just did and it worked. Thank you!